# Filepicker.io Android - how I can upload file and get response Url?

Tags: filepicker.io

I have some troubles with integrating Android app with FilePicker.io.
I would like to upload photo to my FilerPicker storage and get response url to this image.
I do not see any method for doing this.

There is example what I need working in web panel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the web dialog on an android device? Or are you using the Filepicker android library?

If you are using the library, the answer should be here: https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-android#getting-a-file

The URL is included in the FpFile object.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am using library for Android system.
I also checked the github repository but I do not see antything about it.